# How to use Fn+F5/F6 adjust the backlight

Tags: 14.04, grub2, backlight

My NB is Asus N500JK and OS is Kubuntu 14.04.

I try modify `/etc/default/grub` file.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

then

```
update-grub
```

After reboot, it can use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5/F6</kbd> adjust backlight.
But backlight level only 10, and no notification UI when I adjust the backlight.

The command `ls /sys/class/backlight/` show three folders:

```
acpi_video0 acpi_video1 intel_backlight
```

Also `max_brightness` file in this three folders has this value:

```
acpi_video0 & acpi_video1 max_brightness -> 10
intel_backlight max_brightness -> 4882
```

How to let system adjust `intel_backlight` and show notification UI when I adjust the backlight?