# Not able to adjust brightness in Thinkpad E14 Laptop

Tags: grub2, brightness, thinkpad, backlight

My Laptop has the following configuration.

- Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz × 8
- Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)
- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- GNOME Version: 3.36.8

I tried the solution [How to use Fn+F5/F6 adjust the backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526354/how-to-use-fnf5-f6-adjust-the-backlight) and now my grub configuration file is as follows:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi="
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I added only `acpi_osi=` at the end of line. My Function keys are now working and also showing brightness level in top right corner. But it's unable to change brightness.

What might be the reason and I also want to know how to debug and understand these things, where should I start learning about these issues? I'm currently a Web Application Developer but I want to learn more about Linux internals and how things interact with Hardware.

Thanks

Comment: llvmpipe means you are completely software rendering - hardly using your GPU. I'd expected an intel driver. Try to switch to intel and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are still using the 5.4 kernel which does not support the "renoir" chips of your hardware.

Try to update to kernel 5.8 and report back if it helped.